# Using a Storyboard as a subview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, subview

I am creating a project in which I'm creating my own custom navigation system by animating subviews on and off screen. One of these subviews is to have a navigation controller, and many other elements that are far easier (in this case) to create with storyboards. I have tried adding a storyboard as a subView with the following code (with little luck).

```
MainSV = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainSubView"];

[self.view addSubview:MainSV];
```

I am receiving the following warning.

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIStoryboard *__strong' to
>   parameter of type UIView*'

Now I'm not arguing that the above code should be working or anything because I understand the error, so what I'm asking is, how can I through this method or any other, add a storyboard as a subview of my `UIView`? Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the containment view controller API, which is only available in iOS 5:

```
[self addChildViewController:mainSV];
[self.view addSubview:mainSV.view];
```

You can read the gotchas etc. in the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html